# Understanding the Behavior of this Code Snippet: Printed Value and Address of Referenced Int Differ

Tags: c++, reference

Consider the following code. It defines a class `Test` with a member variable `int &m` and member function `Print()` that prints the value and address of `m`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
        int &m;
        Test(int n);
        void Print();
};

Test::Test(int n) : m(n) {};
void Test::Print() {cout << m << "\t" << &m << endl; };

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    Test test1(a);
    Test test2(a);
    test1.Print();
    test2.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

It's output is

```
Printing....    2       0x7ffd2744cf0c                                                                                                                                              
Printing....    2       0x7ffd2744cf08
```

If I change the constructor `Test(int n)` to be the following

```
Test::Test(int n) : m(n) {cout << "Constructing\t" << n << "\t" << &n << endl;};
```

I instead get

```
Constructing    2       0x7ffc233ef15c                                                                                                                                              
Constructing    2       0x7ffc233ef15c                                                                                                                                              
Printing....    2       0x7ffc233ef15c                                                                                                                                              
Printing....    32597   0x7ffc233ef15c
```

Why does `m` have value `32597` in `test2`? I see that the address of `m` is now the same between the two `Test` objects `test1` and `test2` but I'm unsure why changing the constructor to output the value and address of it's input `n` would affect the value or address of the variable `m` that `n` is used to instantiate.

Comment: If in relatively trivial code (like yours) there is a weird value involved, you can be sure it's undefined behavior and not a logic bug somewhere.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yeah, I figured it was undefined behavior since `m` in `test2` is random when I run the code. But this is quite literally the first c++ code I've written and I don't understand why changing `Test()` makes the behavior undefined. My understanding is the `cout` statement added to `Test()` doesn't change `n` or `m`. Any thoughts on what is happening?

Comment: You know, it's undefined for a reason. Maybe if you add `int a = 9;` at the end of your code, your computer will explode. Who knows :P

Comment: @Rakete1111 Ha, I don't much about c++, but I've heard about the dangers of overwriting memory. Maybe I'll try that once I know what it might do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're storing a reference to the parameter `n`, and `n`'s lifetime ends when the constructor finishes executing.

Any use of `m` after that point is undefined, as the object it refers to does no longer exist.

Your program may appear to do something that seems reasonable, or it may do something that's just weird, but it's not a valid C++ program.

Comment: Appreciate the response. Could you briefly explain why `m` seems defined in the initial piece of code since it does output `2` for both `Test` objects? Somehow, does adding `cout` to `Test()` change the lifetime of the constructor?

Comment: You can't tell by inspecting a C++ program's behaviour that it's *not* undefined. What's probably happening is that the value of the "dead" object hasn't yet been overwritten when you read it, but this is just bad luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `n` by copy.

The constructor is creating a reference to the **copy**.

The copy disappears after the constructor is called.

The reference is undefined since the copy has disappeared.

Make the parameter in your constructor `int& n` as in `Test(int& n)`.